# Bash Ordering csv by colum not as expected with numbers an spaces at the end of the string

Tags: bash, csv, sorting

sorry for my bad english, im an italian girl.
I have a folder plenty of csv in .txt format with data inside separated by ";" that i want to order alphabetically by the second column( the name of the game ).

Thats an example of one little part of one of the the csv .txt inside my folder
e.g. Arcade.txt

```
ms4plus;Metal Slug 5;Arcade;mslug4;2002;bootleg;Platform / Shooter Scrolling;;;;;0;;;;;ì
ms4plus;Metal Slug;Arcade;mslug4;2002;bootleg;Platform / Shooter Scrolling;;;;;0;;;;;
ms4plus;Metal Slug 3;Arcade;mslug4;2002;bootleg;Platform / Shooter Scrolling;;;;;0;;;;;
ms4plus;Metal Slug 6;Arcade;mslug4;2002;bootleg;Platform / Shooter Scrolling;;;;;0;;;;;
ms4plus;Metal Slug 4 Plus;Arcade;mslug4;2002;bootleg;Platform / Shooter Scrolling;;;;;0;;;;;
ms4plus;Metal Slug 4;Arcade;mslug4;2002;bootleg;Platform / Shooter Scrolling;;;;;0;;;;;
ms4plus;Metal Slug 2;Arcade;mslug4;2002;bootleg;Platform / Shooter Scrolling;;;;;0;;;;;
```

I've made this bash script that does **quite** WELL the work:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.txt
do
        tmpfile="${f}.tmp"
        sort --field-separator=';' --key=2 "$f" > "$tmpfile"
        rm -rf "$f"
        mv "$tmpfile" "$f"
done
```

**IT WORKS WELL EXCEPT** one important thing;
In fact the output is:

```
ms4plus;Metal Slug 2;Arcade;mslug4;2002;bootleg;Platform / Shooter Scrolling;;;;;0;;;;;
ms4plus;Metal Slug 3;Arcade;mslug4;2002;bootleg;Platform / Shooter Scrolling;;;;;0;;;;;
ms4plus;Metal Slug 4;Arcade;mslug4;2002;bootleg;Platform / Shooter Scrolling;;;;;0;;;;;
ms4plus;Metal Slug 4 Plus;Arcade;mslug4;2002;bootleg;Platform / Shooter Scrolling;;;;;0;;;;;
ms4plus;Metal Slug 5;Arcade;mslug4;2002;bootleg;Platform / Shooter Scrolling;;;;;0;;;;;ì
ms4plus;Metal Slug 6;Arcade;mslug4;2002;bootleg;Platform / Shooter Scrolling;;;;;0;;;;;
ms4plus;Metal Slug;Arcade;mslug4;2002;bootleg;Platform / Shooter Scrolling;;;;;0;;;;;
```

In fact, as you can see, "Metal Slug" ( withouut numers at the end ) is the LAST entry of the output, but it should be the first one!
How can i change my script to do that?
Thanks in advice for your help

Comment: This is a common FAQ; you need `--key=2,2`